# avaudiorecorder interruption in background

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In my application I am using `AVAudioRecorder` for recording. Its works fine. but while I am recording in background if a device audio is played my recording get interrupted. I have the delegate function in my code. But its not getting called.

Comment: Do you mean, you can play audio in the background and you cannot record it when some other audio interrupts?

Comment: if possible i need to record the audio even if the device is playing a music

Comment: You will need the keep the AVAudioRecorder as an Instance object which will stay forever to achieve any background operations. It works fine for the background audio, but I am not sure if you can record the audio the same way.

Comment: i made my audio recorder as AppDelegate Property is that enough ?

Comment: my audio file is getting played in background but its also getting interrupted by device player.

Comment: Thats makes sense. Suggested behaviour from Apple is that your audio will automatically be stopped whenever u r interrupted. So You will have to handle the End interruption callbacks to resume the audio. Please check this below source for further details. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Comment: @PraveenKumar,how can you record sound in background? could you share some codes? I'm doing similiar, but can not record sound. Below is my way: [_recorder updateMeters];[_recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];

Comment: @Jacky: I have mentioned in the above comment that I am not sure if you can record audio in the same way i.e in background. So I am sorry, I dont have any codes to share regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

An app that plays audio continuously (even while the app is running in the background) can register as a background audio app by including the UIBackgroundModes key (with the value audio) in its Info.plist file. Apps that include this key must play audible content to the user while in the background.

Check below links
  [Link 1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW32)

You need to make couple of changes in plist file.

1) Set Required background mode to App plays audio

2) set Application does not run in background to YES.

3) Add following code to AppDelegate

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```